# How to chunk large documents and realign the labels for entity extraction task using BERT models using python

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition

I have a need to extract entities from pdf documents. Documents can be in the range of 1 to 5 pages. After doing OCR on these documents we pass it through

When doing tokenization using Deep learning models, say BERT models sometimes it doesn't fit into tokens limit.

Let's take an example of training sample:

**Input**

```
{'text': 'Robert Nesta Marley OM (6 February 1945 – 11 May 1981) was a Jamaican reggae and singer, guitarist, and songwriter. Born in Nine Mile, Jamaica, Marley began his professional musical career in 1963',
 
'spans': 
    'spans': [
        {'start': 0, 'end': 19, 'label': 'name', 'ngram': 'Robert Nesta Marley'},
        {'start': 24, 'end': 39, 'label': 'date', 'ngram': '6 February 1945'},
        {'start': 125, 'end': 143, 'label': 'loc', 'ngram': 'Nine Mile, Jamaica'},
        {'start': 193, 'end': 197, 'label': 'date', 'ngram': '1963'},
]}
```

Assume the character limit is 20 for tokenization model, then in that case I want to chunk the text and spans as separate training examples like this keeping in mind that in chunked document we get complete entity and not partial entities. Also for chunked document the index will start from 0 and spans will change.

**Expected Output**

```
{'text': 'Robert Nesta Marley ,
 
'spans': 
    [
    {'start': 0, 'end': 19, 'label': 'name', 'ngram': 'Robert Nesta Marley'},
  
    ]
}


{'text': 'OM (6 February 1945 –',
 
'spans': 
    [

  {'start': 4,'end': 19,'label': 'date', 'ngram': '6 February 1945'},
    ]
}

{'text': ' 11 May 1981) was a Jam',
 
'spans': 
    [
    ]
}

{'text': 'aican reggae singer,'
 
'spans': 
    [
    ]
}

{'text': 'guitarist, and songwrit'
 
'spans': 
    [
    ]
}

{'text': 'er. Born in '
 
'spans': 
    [
    ]
}
{'text': 'Nine Mile, Jamaica, '
 
'spans': 
    [
  {'start': 0, 'end': 18, 'label': 'loc', 'ngram': 'Nine Mile, Jamaica'},
    ]
}
```

Notice that `Nine Mile, Jamaica` is put into next document as previous document would have fit only partial text of this entity.

Code Not correct:

```
def chunk_text_and_spans(input_data, max_characters):
    chunked_data = []
    remaining_text = input_data['text']
    remaining_spans = input_data['spans']
    start_index = 0

    while remaining_text:
        # Calculate the chunk size based on the remaining text and the character limit
        chunk_size = min(len(remaining_text), max_characters)
        
        # Check if the chunk contains a partial entity
        partial_entity = any(start_index <= span['start'] < start_index + chunk_size for span in remaining_spans)

        if partial_entity:
            # Find the end of the last complete word before the entity
            chunk_size = remaining_text.find(' ', chunk_size // 2, chunk_size)

        # Adjust chunk size to ensure that no span is split across chunks
        while any(start_index + chunk_size < span['end'] for span in remaining_spans):
            chunk_size = remaining_text.rfind(' ', 0, chunk_size)

        # Adjust chunk size to ensure that it covers at least one complete word
        while chunk_size < len(remaining_text) and remaining_text[chunk_size] != ' ':
            chunk_size += 1

        chunk_text = remaining_text[:chunk_size]
        
        # Update remaining text
        remaining_text = remaining_text[chunk_size:]
        
        # Get adjusted spans for the current chunk
        adjusted_spans = adjust_spans_for_chunk(remaining_spans, start_index, start_index + chunk_size)

        # Append the chunked data
        chunked_data.append({'text': chunk_text, 'spans': adjusted_spans})

        # Update start index for next chunk
        start_index += chunk_size

    return chunked_data

# Example usage
input_data = {
    'text': 'Robert Nesta Marley OM (6 February 1945 – 11 May 1981) was a Jamaican reggae and singer, guitarist, and songwriter. Born in Nine Mile, Jamaica, Marley began his professional musical career in 1963.',
    'spans': [
        {'start': 0, 'end': 19, 'label': 'name', 'ngram': 'Robert Nesta Marley'},
        {'start': 24, 'end': 39, 'label': 'date', 'ngram': '6 February 1945'},
        {'start': 125, 'end': 143, 'label': 'loc', 'ngram': 'Nine Mile, Jamaica'},
        {'start': 193, 'end': 197, 'label': 'date', 'ngram': '1963'},
    ]
}
max_characters = 20

chunked_data = chunk_text_and_spans(input_data, max_characters)
for chunk in chunked_data:
    print(chunk)
```

How to correctly write this in python code?

Also does it make sense from model training perspective to do chunking like this and train say BERT model? Will position embedding will play a role here? As we are re assigning the labels spans so we are losing relation between first and last page?